# How to get selected item from RadListView?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, telerik

My RadListView is bound to a List of objects. My XAML looks like this:

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="ListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTapped="ListView_OnCellTapped">
```

And here's my event method:

```
void ListView_OnCellTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var obj = ListView.SelectedItem;
}
```

However, the SelectedItem always returns null. I suspect that I need to get the selected object from the EventArgs, but I'm not sure how as the Items collection contained in e isn't directly accessible. Any ideas?

edit 1: Here's my XAML:

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="ListViewMachines" HeightRequest="357" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTapped="ListViewMachines_OnItemTapped">
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell Tapped="Cell_OnTapped">
                <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>

                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="16, 0, 0, 0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Row="0" Column="0">
                            <iconize:IconImage IconSize="25" IconColor="Green" Icon="fa-cogs"></iconize:IconImage>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Row="0" Column="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding MachineName}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
            </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView.GroupDescriptors>
        <telerikListView:PropertyGroupDescriptor PropertyName="FunctionalLocationName"/>
    </telerikDataControls:RadListView.GroupDescriptors>
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#C1C1C1">
                <Label Text="{Binding }" TextColor="#303030" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikDataControls:RadListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```

I've tried adding ItemTapped and SelectionChanged to telerikDataControls:RadListView but neither return the selected object.

Comment: Use `ItemSelected` on your ListView instead of tapped and the `e.SelectedItem as Type` is your object

Answer (score 1):

Get `SelectedCells` of GridView like this:

```
if (this.radGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
{
     GridViewSelectedCellsCollection selectedCells = this.radGridView1.SelectedCells;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a RadListView, not a RadGridView. I updated my original question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the SelectedItem always returns null.

As your description, you may need `ItemSelected="OnSelection"` in XAML instead of `ItemTapped`.

According to the [Xamarin.Forms ListView Sample: Interactivity](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/interactivity/), the selected action can be like this:

```
    void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
            return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
        }
        DisplayAlert ("Item Selected", e.SelectedItem.ToString (), "Ok");
        //comment out if you want to keep selections
        ListView lst = (ListView)sender;
        lst.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

So, the selected item can be get as the sample code([link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/ListView/Interactivity/interactivityListView/interactivityListView/Views/interactiveListViewCode.cs#L32)):

```
e.SelectedItem
```

Notice that, use `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` as the parameter type instead of `EventArgs`. Then you can use `e.SelectedItem` to get the selected item directly.

Comment: Where do I put the ItemSelected="OnSelection" attribute in my xaml? Non of the RadListView tags have that attribute. See my OP for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the snippets guys, but I managed to find how to do this using the ItemTapped event:

```
private void ListView_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTapEventArgs e)
{
  var obj = e.Item as MyObjectType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my XAML code

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="clientView" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
            <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                        <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Margin="10" Text="{Binding Client}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                    </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
        </telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```

Then in the C# to get the selection

```
        async private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTapEventArgs e)
    {
        Client selectedClient = e.Item as Client;

        //open details page
        var masterdetailpage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
        var clientDetails = new ClientDetails(); //page
        clientDetails.BindingContext = selectedClient; //passing data

        await masterdetailpage.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(clientDetails);

    }
```